# Unable to run react native app, which was working before.specifically after installation of prop-types module got failed

Tags: android, react-native

Following is the error which I receive when I try to run project.
I tried restarting server several times. Even unable to install new modules. (tried installing prop-types)

The development server returned response error code: 500

```
URL: http://10.0.3.2:8088/index.android.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&minify=false

Body: {"from":"C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\NewRNPro\\node_modules\\react\\cjs\\react.production.min.js","to":"prop-types","message":"Unable to resolve module `prop-types` from `C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\NewRNPro\\node_modules\\react\\cjs\\react.production.min.js`: Module does not exist in the module map or in these directories:\n  C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\node_modules\n\nThis might be related to https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968\nTo resolve try the following:\n  1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.\n  2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.\n  3. Reset packager cache: `rm -fr $TMPDIR/react-*` or `npm start --
--reset-cache`.","name":"UnableToResolveError","type":"UnableToResolveError","errors":[{}]} processBundleResult
    BundleDownloader.java:170 access$100
    BundleDownloader.java:39 onResponse
    BundleDownloader.java:139 execute
    RealCall.java:135 run
    NamedRunnable.java:32 runWorker
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113 run
    ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588 run
    Thread.java:818
```

package.json

```
 {
  "name": "NewRNPro",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lottie-react-native": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.47.1",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^0.9.0",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-drawer-menu": "^0.2.4",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.16.0",
    "react-native-gridview": "^0.1.1",
    "react-native-image-slider": "^1.1.5",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.6.7",
    "react-native-snackbar": "^0.4.3",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^3.3.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.3.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "2.1.0",
    "jest": "20.0.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Post your question in proper format please.

Comment: Post your package.json please.

Comment: **server returned response error code: 500** Mean you need to check your Server . Restart your server

Comment: This will happen periodically when you download new libraries.  The cache is still saying that you don't have Prop Types installed, but you do. Follow the suggestions in the error (clearing cache and watchman, etc.). And if that doesn't work, restart the server.  Soon, you'll be a boss at the quirks of RN.  It might be good to make sure Prop Types is listed in your package.json file as well.